# Haskell: Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to create a simple function that manipulates a string similar to `toLower`, `toUpper`, and `switchCase` in other languages. However, whenever I try to pass `isUpper` or `isLower` into the template function, it throws at me this error.

```
* Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected: [Char] -> Bool
        Actual: Char -> Bool
    * In the second argument of `lambdaTextConv', namely `isLower'
      In the expression: lambdaTextConv str isLower
      In an equation for `toLower':
          toLower str = lambdaTextConv str isLower
   |
53 | toLower str = lambdaTextConv str isLower
   |                                  ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

The code itself is a simple function that takes a string, and switches cases whenever appropriate.

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe  

letters = take 26 (zip ['A'..] ['a'..])
upperLetters = ['A'..'Z']
lowerLetters = ['a'..'z']

lambdaTextConv str ltrFnc =
    [
        lambdaNewLetter x ltrFnc
    | x <- str ]
lambdaNewLetter x ltrFnc =
    if (ltrFnc x)
    then x
    else ((switchCase x:[]) !! 0)

isUpper char = char `elemIndex` upperLetters /= Nothing
isLower char = char `elemIndex` lowerLetters /= Nothing

toUpper str = lambdaTextConv str isUpper
toLower str = lambdaTextConv str isLower

switchCase str =
    [
        if (isUpper x)
        then snd(letters !! fromJust(x `elemIndex` upperLetters))
        else fst(letters !! fromJust(x `elemIndex` lowerLetters))
    | x <- str ]
```

Comment: Haskell has inferred that `isLower` has the type `Char -> Bool` but the second argument to `lambdaTextConv` is supposed to be `String -> Bool` (`String` is another name for `[Char]`). I suggest you write the type for each function (using `::`) to make sure each function has the type you expect. If one of the functions has the wrong type, the compiler will complain that the `::` declaration doesn't match the actual function, so you'll be able to see which function it is.

Comment: I would *advise* that you given each of your functions a *type*. That way it is easier to locate the problem. While not necessary, defining types for top level definitions is very common.

Comment: @user253751 I am quite aware of the function types, but the problem is that `isLower` is supposed to be of the type `Char -> Bool ` and that is not a mistake. It is only invoked in `lambdaNewLetter` which takes and returns a Char not a String.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check my earlier comment

Comment: @user253751 now looking at your comment I discovered I should have given `lambdaTextConv` a type which fixes the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be really simple. The GHC compiler inferred that `lambdaTextConv` was of type `[Char] -> ([Char] -> Bool) -> [Char]` because of the line

```
    else ((switchCase x:[]) !! 0)
```

when it should have been

```
    else ((switchCase (x:[])) !! 0)
```

The source now looks more like this (imports omitted)

```
letters = take 26 (zip ['A'..] ['a'..])
upperLetters = ['A'..'Z']
lowerLetters = ['a'..'z']

lambdaTextConv :: [Char] -> (Char -> Bool) -> String
lambdaTextConv str ltrFnc =
    [
        lambdaNewLetter x ltrFnc
    | x <- str ]

lambdaNewLetter :: Char -> (Char -> Bool) -> Char
lambdaNewLetter x ltrFnc =
    if (ltrFnc x)
    then x
    else ((switchCase (x:[])) !! 0)

isUpper char = char `elemIndex` upperLetters /= Nothing
isLower char = char `elemIndex` lowerLetters /= Nothing

toUpper str = lambdaTextConv str isUpper
toLower str = lambdaTextConv str isLower

switchCase str =
    [
        if (isUpper x)
        then snd(letters !! fromJust(x `elemIndex` upperLetters))
        else fst(letters !! fromJust(x `elemIndex` lowerLetters))
    | x <- str ]
```